# Removing subscriptions from my Google store possible - really?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-billing

It looks like Google have provided a way to delete in-app subscriptions, but have they?

The Developer API docs have a page [about deleting inApp products](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/delete), and while this could be the old "can delete products, can't delete subscriptions" the page specifically says

> Deletes an in-app product (i.e. a managed product or a subscriptions).

so that seems encouraging, if incorrect grammar.

However, using that endpoint (through the php Api client services) gives me the response

> 400 { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Non-existent in-app product:
> MyPackage/ProductId{productId=CorrectSku}", "errors":
> [ { "message": "Non-existent in-app product:
> MyPackage/ProductId{productId=CorrectSku}", "domain": "global",
> "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

I have made the correct call ($service->inappproducts->delete($package, $sku)) and passed the correct values (why does it refer to sku as "productId"?), so it would appear that the documentation is wrong... or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes", it is now possible (in limited circumstances) to remove a subscription, but no, this was not the way to do it.

Although the inappproducts call on the page I referred to clearly states that it will remove subscriptions, it won't.

The correct call is the [monetization.subscriptions.delete](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions/delete) call.

The limitation is that a subscription with a baseplan can't be deleted.